# Is it possible to output a cs client file to another project?

Tags: nswag

I am trying to use NSwag to generate a client during the build of the project. It does so, but it puts the cs file in a folder directly in the webapi project I am getting the spec file out of.

I want to output it out to another project. Won't making a nuget package during this step be possible if the file is in it's own assembly? Not trying to share the webapi source code.

Comment: Just change the output path to write to another project dir?

Comment: Just saw this and had a slightly different solution. During the build, I made a project using the file and some scripts (trying to have this process automated so that it works for similar projects during their build). But I had another issue (basic authentication) which I just asked as a separate question here.